# How can I print the values of keys returned by heapq?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to obtain the nine keys with the highest values from a large (14m keys) dictionary.

I am using the following to return the nine keys:

```
import heapq

def dict_nlargest(d,n):
    return heapq.nlargest(n ,d, key = lambda k: d[k])

print dict_nlargest(mydict,9)
```

This works, but I would also like to print the values of those keys. Is there a way to do that using this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, iterating over a `dict` iterates over its keys, so only those will be in the heap. You can change that by using `items()` or (preferably) `iteritems()`. You then iterate over (key, value) `tuple`s. The key (for comparison) should be only the value, which can be achieved with `lambda x: x[1]` or (slightly faster) using `operator.itemgetter`.

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

def dict_nlargest_items(d,n):
    return heapq.nlargest(n, d.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))

mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

print dict_nlargest_items(mydict, 2) # [('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

Of course, there is no real need to make this adjustment. Once you have the key, you can always look up the value:

```
print [(k, mydict[k]) for k in dict_nlargest(mydict, 2)] # [('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you TvD, this worked perfectly. Nice explanation as well.